# TFS get project name

Tags: tfs-sdk

I have a team project Named "MyTestTeamProject" under which I have one solution folder. The solution folder contains many class library projects and one windowws application. Under the web application i have a folder named "Database" which contains the sql script file. I need to download script file and execute it in a remote machine.

My snippet for getting all files from a tfs folder is as follows:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_serveruri), creds);
                tfsTeamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
                var versionControl = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>
var workspace = versionControl.CreateWorkspace(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + "-installer", versionControl.AuthorizedUser);
WorkingFolder folder = new WorkingFolder(@"$"+_projectpath+@"\WebApplication1\Database", "c:\\temp");
 workspace.CreateMapping(folder);
                workspace.Get();
```

Here WebApplication1 is my web app under which the database folder exists and '_projectPath' is the team project. How can I get that web proj/ windows project name (WebApplication1) Or the name of the project under which the *Database* folder exists ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a Workspace for that, use the [VersionControlServer.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.downloadfile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method instead.

To locate the item you're looking for use one of the [GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb143084.aspx) methods.